# under what conditions graph will remain connected after removing some edge?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

A graph is connected when there is a path between every pair of vertices. suppose we have an undirected graph, under what conditions graph will remain connected after removing some edge between u and v?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually not much to say — that condition is trivially equivalent to any of the following:

- Between every pair of vertices, there's a path that does *not* include the edge *uv*.
- There is a path from *u* to *v* that does not include the edge *uv*.
- There is a cycle that includes the edge *uv*.

. . . but there's not really anything deeper than that.